# A problem of inequality and request for help

Tags: inequality

Problem

If $n$ be a positive integer, prove that 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} < \frac{1.3.5 \dots (2n-1)}{2.4.6 \dots 2n}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}
\end{align}$$

> Following is my steps to solve the above problem
>
> Taking AM>GM on $1.3.5 \dots (2n−1)$ and $2.4.6 \dots 2n$, separately, we get
>   $1.3.5 \dots (2n−1)<(1+3+5+ \dots (2n-1))^{n-1}=(n(n-1))^{n-1}$
>
> $2.4.6 \dots 2n<(2+4+6+ \dots 2n)^{n}=(n(n+1))^{n}$
>
> Then I tried to prove it but not get the answer. The calculation that I have done is not fruitful.

Comment: Inductive reasoning gives you what you exactly need.

Comment: @Arashium Please help me in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In inductive reasoning, you prove that if something is correct for $n$, then it is correct for $n+1$ too, hence for all number. Of course, it must be correct for 1.

consider the middle value as $a_n$

Then $$a_{n+1}=a_n \times \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$$

You need to prove

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{(n+1)+1}}<a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(n+1)+1}}$$

Here is how to do that:

$$a_{n+1}=a_{n} \times \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} ~~~(I)$$

According to the question

$$a_{n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}} ~~~(II)$$

combine (I) and (II):

$$a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}} \times \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}=\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{2n+2}<\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{2n+1}\stackrel{?}{<}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+3}}$$

This proves the right inequality. Thes same must be done for the left equality. You may ask, how did I conclude the last part:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{2n+1}\stackrel{?}{<}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+3}}$$
if and only if

$$\sqrt{2n+1} \times \sqrt{2n+3} < \sqrt{2n+2} \times \sqrt{2n+1}$$

if and only if

$$(2n+1)(2n+3)<(2n+2)(2n+2)$$

Which is always correct for natural numbers.

To prove the left inequality, you will reach to

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+2}}\stackrel{?}{<}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\times \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n+1}}$$

if and only if

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\stackrel{?}{<}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\times \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n+1}}$$

if and only if

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+2}}\stackrel{?}{<}\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$$

if and only if

$$(n+1)(2n+2)^2<(n+2)(2n+1)^2$$

Comment: Problem is clear. But how to prove?

Comment: The 1st part is clear. Your steps for 1st part is convincing and easy to understand. Thank you very much. Please give hints for the 2nd part.

Comment: @user1942348 See my update

Comment: Convinced. Thank you.